# Ansible copy directory content on remote host

Tags: linux, ansible, copy

I wanna copy directory content from /etc/yum.repos.d to /etc/yum.repos.d.org
I tried like this

```
  - name: copy yum.repos.d content
    synchronize:
      src: /etc/yum.repos.d
      dest: /etc/yum.repos.d.org
```

but when I run this yml

```
[root@master yum.repos.d.org]# ls -al
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   25 11월 29 18:00 .
drwxr-xr-x. 77 root root 8192 11월 29 18:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  324 11월 29 16:16 yum.repos.d
```

There's another directory.
I just want the contents of /etc/yum.repos.d in /etc/yum.repos.d.org

Answer (score 0):

> I just want the contents of /etc/yum.repos.d in /etc/yum.repos.d.org

Use the Ansible [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html), with the remote_src option.

```yaml
- name: copy yum.repos.d content
  copy:
    src: /etc/yum.repos.d/
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d.org
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: It doesn't work...Error is like this ```fatal: [192.168.57.100]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (synchronize) module: remote_src Supported parameters include: _local_rsync_password, _local_rsync_path, _substitute_controller, archive, checksum, compress, copy_links, delete, dest, dest_port, dirs, existing_only, group, link_dest, links, mode, owner, partial, perms, private_key, recursive, rsync_opts, rsync_path, rsync_timeout, set_remote_user, src, ssh_args, times, verify_host"}```

Comment: You're mixing stuff. Use the Copy module, not the synchronize module. Simply copy/paste my code.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! Can I ask `remote_src:yes` means?

Comment: What it means, take a look at the docs for a description!
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-remote_src

Answer (score 0):

Actually the [synchronize module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/synchronize_module.html) takes a parameter called `dirs`, which is used to:

> Transfer directories without recursing.

This will allow you to *copy the contents* of `yum.repos.d` directly to `yum.repos.d.org` instead of the directory itself.

```yaml
    - name: copy yum.repos.d content
      synchronize:
        src: /etc/yum.repos.d/
        dest: /etc/yum.repos.d.org
        dirs: true
```

Comment: I tried like that but it doesn't work 
```[root@master yum.repos.d.org]# ls -al
합계 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   25 11월 30 09:29 .
drwxr-xr-x. 77 root root 8192 11월 30 09:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  324 11월 29 16:16 yum.repos.d```

Comment: Did you copy the code as in my answer and try? Because, it works for me and puts `*.repo` files in `yum.repos.d.org`. Note that the trailing `/` is required for `src` parameter.

Comment: I tried again and it works in 192.168.50.100 (master), but I wanna it works in 192.168.50.101 (datanode) too ! what should I do?

Comment: You can target other nodes using the `- hosts:` directive and run the same task?

Comment: yes Here is /etc/hosts 
```[test]
192.168.50.100
192.168.50.101
```  
I tried - hosts: test and - hosts: all But both are doesn't work

Comment: So this will sync the directory from Ansible controller to *all hosts* that are targeted by `- hosts:`. You may update the question with these updates and any behaviour that is been observed.